# Evaluate $\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the result to the  following limit.

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}$$

I used the following theorem

$$ \lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = w_0 \text{ if }  \lim_{z\to0} f(\frac{1}{z}) = w_0 $$

to rewrite the initial limit to

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z^2}{\overline{z}}$$

I can then derive

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z^2}{\overline{z}} = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}z$$

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z^2}{\overline{z}} = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}\lim_{z\to0}z$$

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z^2}{\overline{z}} = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}(0)$$

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z^2}{\overline{z}} = 0$$

However, what I am confused about is the fact that

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}$$

does not exists. Since approaching the point (0,0) from the real axis gives us 1, whereas approaching it from the imaginary axis gives us -1. So my question is, is it correct to say that the limit to this function is 0?

Comment: Its the limit of $z$ over the conjugate of $z$. They are not at all the same and it was not at all implied that $z$ is a real number.

Comment: Sorry, you are perfectly right. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\left|\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|}\to 0
$$
as $z\to\infty$.

Comment: Can it be said that $\lim f(z) = \lim |f(z)|$ or does that only work for the limit to this function?

Comment: What's true is $| \lim f(z) | = \lim |f(z)|$. In your problem the limit is $0$, so you have a solution.

Comment: @TheValars Look at it as $\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}\leq \left|\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2} \right| \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @EthanBolker but $lim_{n\to \infty}|(-1)^n|\neq |lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n|$

Comment: @gbox Right you are. Add to my comment: If the limit on the left exists.